# Jquery Insert after multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax commenting system and that displays the comment submitted below the form when it has been submitted. I have 2 of the same forms on the page in different places, but only the top form is being reset and the comment inserted bellow it. How can I get it to insert after all instances of the form?

```
$(".reply").keypress(function(event){

var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
     var that    =   this;
//enter pressed

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/private/poll/reply',
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    success: function (data) {
     var parent = $(that).find('input[name=parent]').val();
     //  $("#comment_"+parent).append(data);

       $(data).insertAfter("#comment_"+parent);
        document.getElementById("form_"+parent).reset();



}
});
   }
 });
```

Comment: I'm making an assumption based off your code but you're storing an additional hierarchy of your DOM through hidden fields i.e. the parent? The DOM is a tree structure and you can easily do this without a hidden field through .parent().

Comment: Would be helpful to attach some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you have two inputs using the same ID.  An ID must be unique on the page.  For example, you cannot have `#comment_parent` on the page twice.

What your code is doing is finding the first instance of the `#comment_parent` and using that.  The script will ignore the rest because there should not be more than one `#comment_parent`.

The solution?  Designate unique IDs to the top and bottom forms by using something like `#comment_top_parent` and `#form_top_parent`

Then in your script, update the portion to include that change:

```
   $(data).insertAfter("#comment_top"+parent);
   document.getElementById("form_top"+parent).reset();

   $(data).insertAfter("#comment_bottom"+parent);
   document.getElementById("form_bottom"+parent).reset();
```